# migrate mongodb database to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku

I have now my rails 3.2.1 app running on Heroku.
I've tried to upload the database to mongohq via the heroku mongo:push command, after installing the heroku mongo plugin.

https://github.com/pedro/heroku-mongo-sync

I get the message asking me to confirm if I want to push, but once the push is done, there is nothing my db.

I'm not sure if it is  a problem with heroku or if i'm missing a step.
Could it be that i need to put my app in production mode and migrate the database to production?

I'm not sure how to do that either.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your local heroku connection conform to the plugins assumptions [in the readme's config section]? if not you'll have to set it via:

> export MONGO_URL = mongodb://user:pass@localhost:1234/db

i'll also note, that even after doing this i had to uninstall the heroku plugin and reinstall it from this fork: http://github.com/fjg/heroku-mongo-sync.git

> heroku plugins:install http://github.com/fjg/heroku-mongo-sync.git

Comment: tried that but didn't make a difference, I managed to do the job via mongolabs api at the end.http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20164381-how-do-i-import-export-my-data Cheers

Answer (score 0):

### **Check out the [MongoSync](https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync-ruby)** Ruby Gem

It's a gem I wrote for that very purpose when I had to constantly copy my Local `MongoDB` database to and from my Production DB for a Project (I know it's stupid). It's extremely easy to use. Once you've entered your DB details in the `mongo_sync.yml` file, you can `push` and `pull` DBs using these rake tasks:

```sh
$ rake mongo_sync:push       # Push DB to Remote
$ rake mongo_sync:pull       # Pull DB to Local
```

**Note:** *It's also available as shell script for non-ruby apps: [`mongo-sync`](https://github.com/sheharyarn/mongo-sync)*

[image: mongo-sync demo gif]

Comment: Cheers, i'll have a look :)